# Move element out of screen and then back with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

In the following example the goal is to control the element position with smooth slideIn/Out animation. 
The problem is when the new class is added it overwrites the first one and the second part of animation begins with the reset of element position to 0 and then slidesIn again.
The following snippet will show better what I've tried to explain.

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {

  if (!$('.target').hasClass('hide')) {
   $('.target').addClass('hide')
  } else {
    $('.target').addClass('show')
  }
  
})
```

```css
.target {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.trigger {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes hide{
  0% { transform: translate(0);}
  20% { transform: translate(5px);}
  100% { transform: translate(-120vw);}
}

@keyframes show {
  0% { transform: translate(-120vw);}
  80% { transform: translate(-5px);}
  100% { transform: translate(0);}
}

.hide {
  animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.show {
  animation: show 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='target'>&nbsp;</div>
<button class='trigger'>Trigger</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the animation-delay attribute you have in the `.show` css that should prevent the visible 0.2s reset, as below

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  var target = $('.target');
  if (!target.hasClass('hide')) {
    target.removeClass('show');
   target.addClass('hide');
  } else {
    target.removeClass('hide');
    target.addClass('show');
  }
  
})
```

```css
.target {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.trigger {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes hide{
  0% { transform: translate(0);}
  20% { transform: translate(5px);}
  100% { transform: translate(-120vw);}
}

@keyframes show {
  0% { transform: translate(-120vw);}
  80% { transform: translate(-5px);}
  100% { transform: translate(0vw);}
}

.hide {
  animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.show {
  animation: show 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='target'>&nbsp;</div>
<button class='trigger'>Trigger</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.trigger').click(function() {

  if (!$('.target').hasClass('hide')) {
   $('.target').addClass('hide')
  } else {
    $('.target').css({"transform":"translate(120vw)"});
    $('.target').addClass('show')
  }
  
})
```

```css
.target {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.trigger {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes hide{
  0% { transform: translate(0);}
  20% { transform: translate(5px);}
  100% { transform: translate(-120vw);}
}

@keyframes show {
  0% { transform: translate(-120vw);}
  80% { transform: translate(-5px);}
  100% { transform: translate(0);}
}

.hide {
  animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.show {
  animation: show 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='target'>&nbsp;</div>
<button class='trigger'>Trigger</button>
```